# Do consecutive definitions of the same object names overwrite or append the values in matlab

Tags: matlab, function, syntax

I am trying to translate some code from matlab to R, without having any practical experience coding in matlab. I understand that in matlab you can define multiple objects in a single call to one function like so `[a,b]=fun(x)`. Now I have the case where the defined objects are repeated in two directly consecutive lines of code:

```
[x_min,ind] = min(x_min_vec);
[x_min,ind] = max(x_min_vec);
```

I assume that the first line finds the minimum of `x_min_vec` and its index, saving them in the objects `x_min` and `ind`. But what does the second line do? Does it simply overwrite the objects or are the max value and index appended to the existing objects?
`x_min_vec` is a numeric vector of length>=1.
Thanks for any feedback,
David

Answer (score 2):

Matlab supports object-oriented programming. But those two line of codes are not an example of such. So the second line returns the maximal value and it's location, the `x_min` and `ind` returned by the first line will be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, **it overwrites** both variables with the maximum value of the vector (in `x_min`) and with its index (in `ind`).